# How to keep only one legend in seaborn subplots

Tags: python, visualization, seaborn

I am plotting two subplots using seaborn like so:

```
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2, sharey=True)

sns.swarmplot(flowers[0], flowers[1], hue=colours, ax=ax1)
ax1.set(xlabel='Sepal Length', ylabel='Sepal Width')
plt.legend(loc="upper left", bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1))

sns.swarmplot(flowers[2], flowers[3], hue=colours, ax=ax2)
ax2.set(xlabel='Petal Length', ylabel='Petal Width')

sns.plt.show()
```

However, each subplot has its own legend dictated by colours. Is it possible to remove one of these, and preferably place the remaining outside of the plot? I have tried using `ax1.legend_.remove()` but that didn't work.

Comment: ok I've sorted this with handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
ax.legend(handles[:0], labels[:0])

Comment: You could use [`factorplot`](http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.factorplot.html).

Comment: @mwaskom It's a really great function for what is does, but what if I want to show the difference between two y-values? Factorplot's y parameter can't change from subplot to subplot, so you're left with making different subplots and extracting a unified legend from the hue values. Is this worth another SO question?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

the code to be used is:

```
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2, sharey=True)

sns.swarmplot(flowers[0], flowers[1], hue=colours, ax=ax1)
ax1.set(xlabel='Sepal Length', ylabel='Sepal Width')
plt.legend(loc="upper left", bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1))

sns.swarmplot(flowers[2], flowers[3], hue=colours, ax=ax2)
ax2.set(xlabel='Petal Length', ylabel='Petal Width')
ax2.get_legend().remove()


sns.plt.show()
```